# method's return type is a specific object?

Tags: java

My question is i am creating a class which is reading data from the file and the data is

produce,3554,broccoli,5.99,1

produce,3554,broccoli,5.99,1

produce,3555,carrots,2.23,0.25

produce,3555,carrots,2.23,0.25

produce,3555,carrots,2.23,0.25

----------------------------------------------------// file ends

```
Product[] p= new Product[num];
int k=0;
try
{
   File f = new File("somefile.txt");
   Scanner s= new Scanner(f);
   while(s.hasNextLine())
   {
      String txt = s.nextLine();
      String[] field = txt.split(",");
      p[k] = new Product();//name,code,veg,price,unit are the variable and defined in theparent class named Product and toString method also

      p[k].name=field[0];
      p[k].code=field[1];
      p[k].veg=field[2];
      p[k].price=field[3];
      p[k].unit=field[4];
      k++;
   }
```

Now i want to create a method

```
  public static Product delete(int pos)
  {
      return p[pos]  // this will represent the toString representation of particular inde

  }
```

i am trying this code but this gives me an Exception that p[pos] is not defined

is there any other way out or method to get this method works returning in the form of

object

Comment: Please read the editing hints in the upper right corner of the question editing window and re-edit your code so that it's readable. Right now it's near impossible to read. Edit: never mind as jh314 has done this for you. Please reopen your original question to see what he has done so that your next question won't be so difficult to read.

Comment: Well it could be several things as pointed out by the answers. What do you mean by `p[pos]`? What is `p`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `delete` is `static` but `p` is not. Since static and non-static are separate and not interchangeable, the `delete` method does not recognize it.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It could be the reason. The question is not clear.

Comment: Today is just not my day. I keep posting what I think is the answer and everyone downvotes it. Today, I went from 9 rep to 1 rep and personally, I don't think any of my answers are wrong, just misread.

Comment: Not my down-vote, but the error message should be different if the issue were that of static vs. non-static. The current error message is likely due to scope issue.

Comment: @llamositopia Keep the morale high, some days are to forget ;)

Comment: But since it is static, it wouldn't be defined for the static method? Edit: Seeing his comments on your post solves it.

Comment: @llamositopia He's right, the error message would be like "you cannot access a static variable from an instance method".

Comment: @m0skit0 Yeah, just made an edit to my comment and when I tested it, you're right.

Comment: Yay! I'm banned for too many bad posts in one day! Well, I guess I'm out. Keep answering everybody! I hope you don't get as hated as I did.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a scoping issue. I'm guessing that your p Product array is declared inside of a method or constructor and if so, is visible only inside of that method or constructor. If you want to use the p array in more than one method, it should be declared in the class not in a method or constructor.

Comment: yeah it is declared inside the main method and the delete method is declared outside the main method

Comment: @SYEDSAADALI: then that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of p is not visible in the static namespace. Either move it into the static namespace, or change the function to be not static.